# ComponentDidUpdate causing lag/crash on mobile but not desktop

Tags: reactjs

I have a page in my ReactJs project that shows a product. At the bottom of that page there is a list of similar products. When someone clicks on one of the products in the list they are linked to the same page (Component) that they were already on, the original product page. This changes the product. To update this I dispatch a function that re-fetches the product with the updated id. Example below.

```
componentDidMount() {
    window.scrollTo(0, 0)

    this.props.fetch(this.props.match.params.id);

    this.updateWindowDimensions();
    window.addEventListener('resize', this.updateWindowDimensions);
}

componentDidUpdate(prevProps) {
    if(prevProps.data !== this.props.data) {
        this.updateItem()
    }
}

updateItem = () => {
    this.props.fetch(this.props.match.params.id)
}
```

In my browser things work as expected. Now when I open the application on my phone the page loads, get's laggy, then the server crashes. If I delete the componentDidUpdate function the page load's fine on my phone.

I can't figure out why this is happening and what I can do to fix it. I've tried tweaking things with shouldComponentUpdate() but couldn't get it working. Has anyone run into similar problems?

Comment: This is one of those questions that cannot be resolved on stackoverflow. We have no idea what data you are manipulating, how the other parts of the application look like etc. Connect your phone's browser with your desktops console debug and look at the exact error that you are receiving.

Comment: @Ryne Please explain the structure of `data`. Like Is it an object or a string ?

Comment: it's an object holding a couple keys including a unique id

Comment: also  when I open console for my phone no errors or warning's show up so im not too sure. I have the code on github if you would like to see.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Okay. Let me recite it. Correct me if I'm wrong. You have a product page showing some information about a particular product. I believe the id in URL refers to this product. Next part is when you click on a similar product you the same page to show the information about the product you just clicked. So do change the URL accordingly. 
For example, For a scenario where I clicked on a similar product with id 2 from a product page with id 1, URL should change from /product/1 => /product/2.
Next thing is you need to listen for this ID change in URL in componentDidUpdate like below.

```
 componentDidUpdate(prevProps) {
    console.log(this.props.match.params.id, prevProps.match.params.id);
    //Just to ensure id Change is caught here.

    if(this.props.match.params.id !== prevProps.match.params.id) {
         // Make the fetch Call for the product.
    }
 }
```

Comparing ID's itself is efficient than comparing object and take much lesser time.

Comment: yes exactly I don't know why I didn't think of comparing the param! After reading the way that you described my problem I realized that I could have explained it better myself, sorry. Thank you for the help though this solved my problem! Still not too sure why I was getting the different behavior between browsing devices lol but my problem is solved.

Comment: @Ryne Check this sandbox I created. Comparing object doesn't work in the way you think. https://codesandbox.io/s/serene-northcutt-j46pr

Comment: Interesting. I don't know why I assumed object's would be comparable in such a way, but it is good to know now. Thanks again for taking the time to help and demonstrate in the sanbox!

Comment: It's alright. I mean it's a common mistake I have seen a lot of people doing. Always keep in mind, use lifecycle methods only if it is necessary and do the comparison in the most optimal way. It can affect your application performance. Glad to help :)